What does "the sad gang" mean?
In "Terry Pratchett: A Life With Footnotes" Rob Wilkins writes:

I was definitely a reader of Terry Pratchett. An avid
one, in fact – one whose appearances in the queue at Pratchett book
signings since 1993 (WH Smith, Oxford, for Johnny and the Dead) had
been so conspicuously consistent that he had on his shelves a copy of
the 1997 novel Jingo signed to ‘one of the sad gang’.

What does the phrase "one of the sad gang" mean?.. I've tried to search the Internet, but have found no description and usage in very different contexts...

@MichaelHarvey edited the answer to name him, thank you :) I just tried to be succint and edited question a lot before posting.

In the 1990s, in the UK, 'sad' had an informal meaning: 'pathetically inadequate or unfashionable'. Rob Wilkins was such a frequent attender at Pratchett's book signings that Pratchett jokingly identified him as one of the pathetically inadequate or unfashionable gang of people who attend my book signings'. This is an example of shared self-deprecating humour. Humour is much valued by British people, and Terry Pratchett was no exception.

The word sad is not literal here. It doesn't mean sorrowful/miserable.  It can be used figuratively in a kind of deprecating way, meaning that someone is inadequate, or socially inept. That is what is meant here.
Pratchet wrote that on the book to one of his avid fans (the writer), who would stand in a queue to get books signed (he was one of the 'sad gang'). It's clearly not meant to be deprecating. He was obviously joking with his fans about them being 'sad' for standing in a queue, as if they had nothing better to do with their lives.

British people are famous for their self-deprecating humour.

@Michael Yup, and we are also famous for insulting people we actually like, especially close friends, as a sign of affection.

@BillyKerr thank you for answer, both answers seem almost equal to me, I just accepted the one that was given earlier.

@BillyKerr - These days, speeches by the best man at UK weddings are often very uncomplimentary about the bridegroom - his intelligence, possible homsexuality, gloomy prognostications about the wedding night, suggestions of impotence, premature ejaculation, etc. Rugby club members are particularly known for this. A best man’s speech should last only as long as it takes the groom to make love... [pause 2 seconds] so thank you ladies and gentlemen. I have heard anecdotally of fights breaking out because of ill-judged 'jokes' about the bride.
